# Flink Savepoint restore

Tags: apache-flink, restore

We are currently running flink in Kubernetes. From my understanding is every time we have have a code deployment we need to create a savepoint and then a restore that savepoint after the deployment. Not sure if this correct. My script currently runs this command to grab the job_id and create a savepoint

```html
kubectl exec -it $JOBMANAGER -- flink stop $JOB_ID -- savepointPath
```

I am trying to find the command to do a restore of the latest savepoint. Is the jar file needed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations it is okay to use a retained checkpoint rather than a savepoint. See [this table in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/state/checkpoints_vs_savepoints/#capabilities-and-limitations) for details regarding when a savepoint is necessary. Or if your Flink version is recent enough, you can use native rather than canonical savepoints. The reason to prefer native savepoints (or checkpoints) is this will reduce the downtime.

For the restart, you will do something like this:

```bash
... flink run \
      --detached \ 
      --fromSavepoint /tmp/flink-savepoints/savepoint-cca7bc-bb1e257f0dab \
      ./examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar
```

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#starting-a-job-from-a-savepoint for more about this.